# NetLogo: How To Code Conditional "asks"

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to make it so turtles that have "immune = 0" and "sick = 0" will have a chance of getting sick when colliding with a turtle with "sick = 1".

```
ask turtles with [immune = 0 and sick = 0]
  [if any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1 with [sick = 1] 
    [if (random 100) < infection-rate
      [set sick 1]
    ]
   ]
```

However, the error given is "WITH expected this input to be an agentset, but got a number instead". Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is fine, NetLogo just got confused. This code passes the syntax checker - I added some brackets to the offending line.

```
globals [infection-rate]
turtles-own [immune sick]

to testme
  ask turtles with [immune = 0 and sick = 0]
  [if any? (turtles-on patch-ahead 1) with [sick = 1] 
    [if (random 100) < infection-rate
      [set sick 1]
    ]
   ]
end
```